# LAMP server installaion failed.. localhost does not list directories like codeigniter when copied in var/www/html/

Tags: php, apache2, lamp

i have checked if apache , mysql and php are installed in ubuntu 14.04 using aptitude and all are installed.

but when (file is saved as info.php)

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

the above file is saved in var/www/html directory and when trying to access files from broswer using url localhost/info.php it shows like

[image]

what's the issue? any help?

Comment: What is in your apache error log?

Comment: What's the output of `aptitude search mod-php` and `aptitude search php~i`

Comment: @mkaatman the following is the error    (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:38728] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/infoo.php.save, referer: http://localhost/

Comment: type on the shell console `ls -la /var/www/html/` and `cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep  APACHE_RUN_USER` . Copy the output here.

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or (if you already have those installed)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

in apache's config file

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex Tartan's answer you will also need:

`<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
 </FilesMatch>`

Within your `php5.conf`

This is so instead of serving up an index.html file etc. it will serve up an index.php file.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/286882/apache-is-not-interpreting-php-files